# Why the num_epochs parameter of tf.train.string_input_producer sometimes trigger an OutOfRangeError?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have learned how to use `QueueRunner` and `Coordinator` to read data from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#creating_threads_to_prefetch_using_queuerunner_objects), and applied it to read csv file like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file0.csv"],
                                                num_epochs=1)

reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0]]
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.stack([col1, col2, col3, col4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    # Start populating the filename queue.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    try:
        while not coord.should_stop():
            # Retrieve a single instance:
            example, label = sess.run([features, col5])
            # print(example, label)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print("Epoch limit reached.")
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

While this code runs smoothly, I am curious about the function of `try`, `except` and `finally` statement. So I deleted them, and the corresponding lines become this:

```
while not coord.should_stop():
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])
    # print(example, label)
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Then the code crashed, raising a `OutOfRangeError`:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
    [[Node: ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TextLineReaderV2, input_producer)]]
```

Interestingly, if I change the following code (line 3)

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file0.csv"], num_epochs=1)
```

to

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file0.csv"])
```

the code will not crash, and the data in `file0.csv` can be correctly read.

Why the code crashes when `num_epochs` is set and `try/except/finally` statements are deleted? And why it doesn't crash when `num_epochs` is not set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code crashes due to insufficient element in the queue when  you set the `num_epochs` to 1.

Since you are still running the coordinator 
    `while not coord.should_stop():` Worker threads try to access values from the queue which is exhausted. If the `num_epochs` is not set, by default its value is `None` that means it can cycle through the data an unlimited number of times, so no errors.

When you use `try/except` it handles the queue exhausted signal and gracefully stop the program, no crashes.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that the crashed code actually read out the data before raising the `OutOfRangeError` exception. It's my fault :/ . So when `num_epochs` epochs are reached a `OutOfRangeError` exception will be raised, and `try/except` handles it so the program will not crash.